# Why don't APT connect to HTTP proxy using HTTP `CONNECT`?

Tags: apt, package-management, proxy, http-proxy

Why don't APT connect to HTTP proxy using HTTP `CONNECT`?

I want to use APT with an HTTP proxy, so I've exported the `http_proxy` variable with the address of my server `http://10.10.10.10`.

Now, my server expects a HTTP `CONNECT` request afterwards it starts proxying TCP traffic to the specified host.

However, Wireshark shows that APT doesn't issue HTTP `CONNECT` requests, but instead sends `HTTP GET` requests directly to the proxy server.

Why doesn't APT send HTTP `CONNECT` requests? Isn't that how a HTTP proxy is supposed to work?

Answer (score 3):

`apt` doesn’t use `CONNECT` for HTTP traffic because it doesn’t need to (and arguably, shouldn’t). It does use it for HTTPS traffic.

[`CONNECT`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.6) is used to establish a tunnel through a proxy; typical use cases are to tunnel TLS or SSH traffic through a proxy.

It is not normally used for HTTP traffic. HTTP proxies are supposed to react in the same way as the hosts they proxy for; you’ll see them documented throughout the HTTP RFCs (look at the “Obsoletes” line in [RFC 2616](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616) to find them). Clients send the same requests to a proxy as they would send to the host.

If the proxy server allows it, a client *can* connect to its target host using `CONNECT` through the proxy, but that defeats some of the purposes of using a proxy in the first place. In particular, `CONNECT` tunnels aren’t cached.